# How does one register an assembly in GAC while installation of website?

Tags: .net, asp.net, deployment, gac

I'm working on a project that depends on third party controls.
While opening website after installation, I've an error message regarding these controls,

```
     Could not load file or assembly. assembly_file_name. 
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

web.config file, has an assembly tag for each dll.
When I remove these tags, website is loaded successfully, but while opening any of pages that contains any of these control, I've that error

```
Unknown server tag. tag_name.
```

So I need to register that dll in GAC while installation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either put the assembly in the GAC, or deploy that DLL in the bin\ directory of your ASP.NET application.

You can deploy to the GAC with an MSI, or you can use the `gacutil` utility (it comes with the .NET SDK, but not the redistributable framework itself).

If the DLL is in the bin directory but is not being found, [check here](http://blogs.msdn.com/tom/archive/2008/07/21/asp-net-tips-loading-a-dll-out-of-the-bin-directory.aspx) for some suggestions.

Comment: DLLs of these controls already exist in bin folder of website.

Comment: OK, check the second link then.